# SQL Server & Visual Studio - Insert Data in tables doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

[image]

I want to insert my tables from my SQL Server Management Studio code with data via Visual Studio.

But it doesn't work. The ID of my table doesn't get a value automatically (but I have command it with `identity(1,1)`) and an error appears that it stands in conflict with a foreign-key-constraint.

```
 create table [ProduktZahlungFENutzer] 
 (
 ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 Endpreis decimal(3, 2) 
 );

CREATE TABLE [FHAngehörige]
(
    FHAngehörigeID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) 
        PRIMARY KEY Constraint fhA_feN    
        REFERENCES FENutzer(FENutzerID),
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Fachbereich INT NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE   
)


 CREATE TABLE [FENutzer]
 (
     FENutzerID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL  
          PRIMARY KEY constraint t_nutzer    
          references ProduktZahlungFENutzer(ID),
     Aktiv INT  NOT NULL,
     LetzterLogin datetime  NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
     BENutzerID int NOT NULL 
          constraint FENutzer_BENutzer 
          foreign key references BENutzer(BENutzerID),
     auth_id int not null 
          constraint FENutzer_auth 
          foreign key references auth2(id)
 )
```

Please help

Comment: Why is your primary key that is an identity also a foreign key constraint? It doesn't seem like two identity columns will be in sync unless you do two inserts, one on each table.

Answer (score 0):

You have established a reference

```
FHAngehörigeID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY Constraint fhA_feN    
                                       REFERENCES FENutzer(FENutzerID),
```

This means that you need a record in your table FENutzer.FENutzerID that match FHAngehörigeID, in this case you cannot use IDENTITY

Comment: oh :/ i want a one-to-one-relation between the tables so i need it to references on fhAngehörigeID ,right?  how can i implement then that the primary key gets an automtic value and incremented?

Comment: exactly, you must know the value of FENutzer.FENutzerID

Comment: but all the IDs should be insert automatically, so for that i need to IDENTITY(1,1) ?! so how can i know the value of fenutzer.fenutzerid

Comment: You're referencing ONE field of the second table, and it must exists before you insert the new record.

Comment: but i thought identity would create automatically a value?!

Comment: yes, but you need to assign an existing value in the second table. Usually IDENTITY is useful for PK, but not when this field references another one.

Comment: i edited my question -> would it be possible to set [ProduktZahlungFENutzer] on "1" and then increment it?

Answer (score 0):

Your construction makes no sense - this way, you're creating two tables that depend on each other, at the primary key level - so you would have to have an existing entry in `FENutzer` in order to insert a new row into `FHAngehörige`, and this at the same time is only possible if you already have an existing row in `FHAngehörige` to insert the row in `FEnutzer`.....

You need to clean this up:

- both tables need a **primary key** and the `int identity(1,1)` is a very good choice
- *one* of the tables must reference *the other*, but with a **normal** foreign key attribute - not on the primary key.....

Since you've not given any indication as to which of the tables is the "main" table and which the "child/auxiliary" table, I'm just picking one over the other - so your table structure should be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FHAngehoerige
(
    FHAngehoerigeID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) 
        CONSTRAINT PK_FHAngehoerige PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Fachbereich INT NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE   
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.FENutzer
(
    -- define the PK for the table
    FENutzerID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL  
        CONSTRAINT PK_FENutzer PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    -- define the **foreign key** to the main table
    FHAngehoerigeID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_FENutzer_FHAngehoerige
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.FHAngehoerige(FHAngehoerigeID),
     Aktiv INT  NOT NULL,
     LetzterLogin datetime  NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
     BENutzerID int NOT NULL 
          constraint FENutzer_BENutzer 
          foreign key references BENutzer(BENutzerID),
     auth_id int not null 
          constraint FENutzer_auth 
          foreign key references auth2(id)
 )
```

Also: I would ***strongly recommend*** (from my own personal, bad experience) to ***AVOID*** any special characters like umlauts or accents or anything like that in table and column names.....

Comment: i used the primary key to make a one-to-one-relation beween the tables. is there a different way on how to implement a one-to-one-relation? couldn't find one :(

Comment: i just can add one primary key to a table

Comment: @noclue123: the solution I showed can be used to define a 1:1 relationship - you just **cannot** have two "interlocking" FK constraints referencing each other, both based on an `identity` column - this will **never** work